# ASP.NET Web API upload image to SQL Server database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-web-api, image-uploading

I'm writing an article API with image and I've been following this [tutorial](http://code-adda.com/2018/05/upload-file-on-server-using-asp-net-web-api/) about uploading file in ASP.NET web API, the `Title` and `Content` are saved to database as intended.

The problem here is, the images that I post are saved to my local folder but the fields `Filename`, `Filepath`, `Filelength`, and `Filecreatedtime` aren't saved to database.

Posting article to database with postman:

[image: posting article to database]

The `ImageFolder`:

[image: imageFolder]

`GET` index:

[image: get index]

The database:

[image: article database]

here's my `Article` model:

```
namespace Wwf_Article.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class Article
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Content { get; set; }
        public string FileName { get; set; }
        public string FilePath { get; set; }
        public float FileLength { get; set; }
        public DateTime FileCreatedTime { get; 
    }
}
```

and here's my **POST controller**

```
[Mime]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post()
{

        var fileuploadPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/ImageFolder");

        var multiFormDataStreamProvider = new MultiFileUploadProvider(fileuploadPath);

        await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(multiFormDataStreamProvider);

        string uploadingFileName = multiFormDataStreamProvider.FileData.Select(x => x.LocalFileName).FirstOrDefault();

        Article article = new Article
        {
            Title = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["Title"],
            Content = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["Content"],

            //these four lines below aren't saved to DB 
            FilePath = uploadingFileName,
            FileName = Path.GetFileName(uploadingFileName),
            FileLength = new FileInfo(uploadingFileName).Length,
            FileCreatedTime = DateTime.Now
        };

        db.Articles.Add(article);
        db.SaveChanges();

        return Ok();
}
```

Any idea how to fix this problem?

Comment: You haven't described the problem yet. Do you get no records in the database? It's the wrong filename? Which database are you targeting?

Comment: BTW this `Post()` action is definitely *not* suitable for Web API. The request data should appear in the *parameters*. You should *NOT* access the Request, much less the context, this way. How are you going to test that method if there's no context?

Comment: ah sorry, I thought the the question is already clear from the controller itself. But yes, the filename, path, length, and createdtime got no records in database but the files themselves are uploaded to the folder

Comment: Are you looking in the *correct* database? What does the connection string, DbContext configuration look like? If you use a user instance SQL database, ie you try to connect to an `mdf` file, you may be looking at the *wrong* database - during debugging the "current" folder is `bin\debug\` and any changes are written into the `bin\Debug\App_Data` folder.

Comment: and when I put my `Article` paramater to the request data, it always got an error with `"The request entity's media type 'multipart/form-data' is not supported for this resource."`

Comment: @retrospectrum I suspect this line of code `string uploadingFileName = multiFormDataStreamProvider.FileData.Select(x => x.LocalFileName).FirstOrDefault();` is returning null. Put a breakpoint on this line of code and check.

Comment: so what you are looking for do you wanna add those fileds in database ?

Comment: @MohsinMehmood after I put breakpoint on it, yes the `uploadingFileName` does returns a null

@ArunprasanthKV the fields are already in database, I want those fields return a value in database

Comment: What i understand from this post method is You are trying to read the files from a folder and then take the first file and save the information from that fine into database. But your code is not able to read files correctly. You could try this to get the files information ` DirectoryInfo d= new DirectoryInfo(strFolderPath);
       //file extension for pdf
        var files = d.GetFiles("*.img*");
        FileInfo[] subfileInfo = files.ToArray<FileInfo>();`

Answer (score 0):

Are the 4 four lines below as you mentionned part of your Article model class?
I mean (FilePath, FileName, FileLength and FileCreatedTime)

Comment: yes, I added the model to the question for more clarification

Comment: Yeah i have seen the model class

Comment: You can pass a base-64 file or image to the content column in either Postman or swagger when testing

Answer (score 0):

1- If yes, i think you can use a stored procedure to achieve your request like the following

```
  CREATE PROC spInsertArticle
   @Title varchar(100),
   @Content varchar(100),
   @FileName varchar(500),
   @FilePath varchar(500),
   @FileLength varchar(500)

AS

  Insert Into ArticleTable(Title,Content,FileName,
        FilePath,FileLength,FileContentTime)
    Values (@Title,@Content,@FileName,
        @FilePath,@FileLength,GetDate())
```

2-Go back to your api project and create a model class called ArticleModel:

```
        public class ArticleModel
        {
           public string Title {get; set; }
           public string Content {get; set; }
           public string FileName {get; set; }
           public string FilePath {get; set; }
           public string FileLength {get; set; }
        }
```

3-Create an api post method in the ArticleController

```
  [Route("api/ArticleController/PostArticle")]
    public HttpResponseMessage PostArticle(ArticleModel obj)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                string PhotoPath =        Convert.ToString(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ImagePath"]);

                ArticleModel newObj = new ArticleModel();

                newObj.Title  = obj.Title ;
                newObj.Content = obj.Content;
                newObj.FileName = obj.FileName;
                newObj.FilePath = obj.FilePath;
                newObjl.FileLength = obj.FileLength;

                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(newObj.Content))
                {

                }
                else
                {                        
                    string startingFilePath = PhotoPath;

                    string FilePath = SaveImage(newObj.Content, startingFilePath, newObj.FileName);

                    FileInfo fInfo = new FileInfo(FilePath);

                    newObj.Content = fInfo.Name;
                }

                ArticleEntities context = new ArticleEntities();
                var newArticle = context.spInsertArticle(newObj.Title, newObj.Content,
                newObj.FileName, newObj.FilePath, newObj.FileLength);

                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, newArticle);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, ex);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ModelState);
        }
    }
```

4-And finally create the SaveImage method mentionned in the PostArticle method

```
    private string SaveImage(string base64, string FilePath, string ImageName)
    {
        //Get the file type to save in
        var FilePathWithExtension = "";
        string localBase64 = "";

        if (base64.Contains("data:image/jpeg;base64,"))
        {
            FilePathWithExtension = FilePath + ImageName + ".jpg";
            localBase64 = base64.Replace("data:image/jpeg;base64,", "");
        }
        else if (base64.Contains("data:image/png;base64,"))
        {
            FilePathWithExtension = FilePath + ImageName + ".png";
            localBase64 = base64.Replace("data:image/png;base64,", "");
        }
        else if (base64.Contains("data:image/bmp;base64"))
        {
            FilePathWithExtension = FilePath + ImageName + ".bmp";
            localBase64 = base64.Replace("data:image/bmp;base64", "");
        }
        else if (base64.Contains("data:application/msword;base64,"))
        {
            FilePathWithExtension = FilePath + ImageName + ".doc";
            localBase64 = base64.Replace("data:application/msword;base64,", "");
        }
        else if (base64.Contains("data:application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document;base64,"))
        {
            FilePathWithExtension = FilePath + ImageName + ".docx";
            localBase64 = base64.Replace("data:application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document;base64,", "");
        }
        else if (base64.Contains("data:application/pdf;base64,"))
        {
            FilePathWithExtension = FilePath + ImageName + ".pdf";
            localBase64 = base64.Replace("data:application/pdf;base64,", "");
        }

        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(localBase64)))
        {
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(FilePathWithExtension, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
            {
                //Create the specified directory if it does not exist
                var photofolder = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(FilePathWithExtension);
                if (!Directory.Exists(photofolder))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(photofolder);
                }

                ms.WriteTo(fs);
                fs.Close();
                ms.Close();
            }
        }

        return FilePathWithExtension;
    }
```

5-Try this in either Postman or swagger and it will work for you. I am available for any discussion

Comment: I'm sorry, I've never use a stored procedure before. do I create a new table or rewrite my old `Article` table?

Comment: Just a side note to stick with coding standards, Use camelCase for parameter names and local variables. And if you have many if else ladder then go for switch because switch uses binary search/Jump tables so its faster.and here instead of using both you can go for dictionaries and in a single line you can get the result

Comment: also to clarify, `content` field isn't the content of the image. it's the content of the article

Comment: No do not rewrite your table but you can copy the procedure and change the datatypes according to yours and and execute it

Comment: Which field takes the image?

Comment: After creating the procedure, go to your api project and use edmx to call the procedure. Generate a function import for the procedure

Comment: Give me a minute to work around it without a stored procedure

Comment: @Somad from the [tutorial](http://code-adda.com/2018/05/upload-file-on-server-using-asp-net-web-api/), they only have those `FileName`, `FilePath`, `FileLength` and `FileCreatedTime` fields for the image. should I add another field?

Comment: You can use a generic repo and UnitOfWork to do that

Comment: The link of your tutorial http://code-adda.com/2018/05/upload-file-on-server-using-asp-net-web-api/ give 500 Internal Server Error

Answer (score 0):

First of all, create a Generic interface repo class

```
   public interface IRepository<T> where T : class
   {
        T GetById(int id);
        void Add(T entity);
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a class that will implement the interface

```
        public class EFRepository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
        {
                   public EFRepository(PayrollcshrnewEntities dbContext)
                    {
                            if (dbContext == null)
                                  throw new ArgumentNullException("dbContext");
                            DbContext = dbContext;
                            DbSet = DbContext.Set<T>();
          }

           protected ArticleEntities DbContext { get; set; }

           protected DbSet<T> DbSet { get; set; }

                public virtual T GetById(int id)
                {            
                       return DbSet.Find(id);
                 }

                 public virtual void Add(T entity)
                 {
                      DbEntityEntry dbEntityEntry = DbContext.Entry(entity);
                      if (dbEntityEntry.State != EntityState.Detached)
                      {
                            dbEntityEntry.State = EntityState.Added;
                       }
                       else
                      {
                              DbSet.Add(entity);
                       }
              }
          }
```

Comment: Kindly replace PayrollcshrnewEntities with ArticleEntities  in the constructor class of the Generic Repo class

Comment: sorry for the late reply, I just got home from work. give me some minutes to implement this

Answer (score 0):

For some reason after I delete the edmx and recreate the EF designer table with ADO, the POST controller works.

It turns out there's missing fields in the edmx diagram.

Thanks for all the help anyway, guys